# Why isn't $\int\sin^2(x)dx=2\ln(\csc(x))+c$?

Tags: calculus

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but since $$\int\frac{1}{x}{ dx}=\ln(x)+c$$and $$\sin^2(x)=\frac{1}{\csc^2(x)}$$Why isn't $$\int\sin^2(x)dx=2\ln(\csc(x))+c$$?

Comment: Continue diligently with your Calculus 90 coursework, you'll understand and we're cheering for you!

Comment: If that happens $$\int f(x)dx=\int \frac{1}{1/f(x)} dx=\ln(f(x))+\text{C}$$. Isn't that strange?

Comment: @DARK You’re missing a negative sign, I presume.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oops . thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is the essence of the chain rule:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \bigl[ \ln(\csc^2 x) \bigr]
= \frac{1}{\csc^2 x} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \bigl[ \csc^2 x \bigr]
$$
You're essentially asking if you can ignore the derivative in gray:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \bigl[ \ln(\csc^2 x) \bigr]
= \frac{1}{\csc^2 x} \color{gray}{\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \bigl[ \csc^2 x \bigr]}
$$
but you can't! The [method of substitution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Integration_by_substitution) makes precise how to correctly reverse engineer the chain rule for derivatives when approaching integrals.